# Auto submit login form and start session

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I am trying to auto submit login form by using javascript but it cannot start session and redirect to same page but when i am try to submit same form without javascript it working.
I need to submit form automatically. Any suggestion?

```
<?php include('_header.php'); ?>
    <form id="my_form" method="post" action="index.php" name="loginform">
        <label for="user_name"><?php echo WORDING_USERNAME; ?></label>
        <input id="user_name" type="text" value="something" name="user_name" required />
        <label for="user_password"><?php echo WORDING_PASSWORD; ?></label>
        <input id="user_password" type="hidden" value="something1" name="user_password" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="user_rememberme" name="user_rememberme" value="1" />
        <label for="user_rememberme"><?php echo WORDING_REMEMBER_ME; ?></label>
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="<?php echo WORDING_LOGIN; ?>" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submitForm() {
            document.getElementById('my_form').submit();
        }
        window.onload = submitForm;
    </script>
    <a href="register.php"><?php echo WORDING_REGISTER_NEW_ACCOUNT; ?></a>
    <a href="password_reset.php"><?php echo WORDING_FORGOT_MY_PASSWORD; ?></a>
<?php include('_footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: what does "using java but it cannot start session and redirect to same page" mean?

Comment: i assume it's means `javascript`.

Comment: hello  YOU ARE using JAVA or PHP ?

Comment: @DS9  ,he is combining JAVA + PHP code

Comment: sorry, i am beginners... i means to say, i am not redirect to logged in page. I get same login form again and again. but when i remove <script>.....</script> it works fine.

Comment: @ jQuery Angry Bird ,he is using javascript tag and his code contain javascript.

Comment: For one thing, you're using jQuery yet using vanilla js? Change `document.getElementById('my_form').submit();` to simply `$('#my_form').submit();`, also, at that point, `window.onload = submitForm` only give `.onload` a new method, it doesnt fire it. Change `window.onload = submitForm;` to `submitForm();` or remove the function all together and just put in `<script>$('#my_form').submit();</script>` and it'll `autosubmit`

Comment: You need to make sure that JS part that submits form doesnt do it over and over again, ie if there is a form submition and user is loged in or not, next time you show a page do not fire form.submit() anymore

Comment: @BojanT If his login-script has any logic, it wont send him in a loop, because when it is auto submitted, he gets logged in and not shown the login page again. This autosubmit-javascript code should only be included for example if a user has a cookie saying he has remember username / password

Comment: So, finally i found way to submit form automtically, i just replace <input type="submit" to <input type="hidden". Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to autosubmit your form upon page visit you simply put this code after your form:

```
<script>
     document.getElementById('my_form').submit();
</script>
```

Comment: He's using jQuery, he can also just simply `$('#my_form').submit();`

Comment: getElementById is about 90% more efficient than jQuery. Anyhow, the result will be the same and it doesnt matter

Comment: `"90% more effecient"`? Seriously, one of these stupid arguments? He's using jQuery. If you're not going to use the library to it's full capability, there's no point in using it at all. Also, jQuery's way is A LOT easier to read, and "efficiency" in the day and age of Tygra Processors and quad-core intel being standard or less than standard in many places, NO. It's no long more efficient. You're not saving anything. The nanoseconds of time saved are more real time seconds time spent reading, writing, and reviewing code that could have been simplified and the job done.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-javascript-performance-comparison/22 say whatever you like, my point is still valid. Both codes do the exact same thing, so what he is trying to achieve will still be achieved. And yes, it is more efficient.

Comment: No it's not more efficient. Efficiency includes not only time for the JS engine to read the code, but time to write it, review it, and read it from a programmer stand point. In which case, it's not more efficient. While you argue in vain to use Vanilla WITH jQuery, you ignore the fact, maintaining Vanilla within using a lib like jQuery is only mere nanoseconds of time saved on the user end, however it's many whole seconds, which turn into minutes, which quickly become hours of wasted production and maintenance time all so you could save a few unnoticed nanoseconds.

Comment: If he was ONLY going to use JS, I'd say you're right, but he's not stated as much. In fact, by tagging it jQuery, he's already shown interest in jQuery usage and shown that he has the lib at use, so why not use it correctly? You wouldn't buy a souped up Mustang and then drive it slow on the interstate when no one is around for miles, just because it's better gas millage, would you?

Comment: Same problem happening, getting same login form again and again

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you are submiting form over and over again, try this, check if form has already been submited and if not submit a form otherwise skip submition

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function submitForm() {
            document.getElementById('my_form').submit();
        }
 <?php if(!isset($_REQUEST['login']) ) : ?>  window.onload = submitForm; <?php endif ?>

</script>
```

Comment: I also prefer jQuery but he has time to learn it and see for him self benefits of using it. `$('#someid').load(someExternalUrl)` I dont even know how to do it in native JS

Comment: Getting error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in....." line 23

Comment: Sorry add `<?php endif ?>`  instead of `<? endif ?>` The second one is valid if you have short open tags in php.ini but you don't seem to have set that and it is not by default. I do recomend it as it is much easier in templates to use ie `<?=$var ?> ` than long version